# Upload multiple Images Separately and with Different Buttons

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload

I need users to upload several photos, separately and in order, using Html and Javascript. There must be one button per image upload.

I have used JQuery, but it only works with one button, not several.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#image1, #image2')
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .width(300)
        .height();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <img src="..." alt="Profile Image1" id='image1' class="profileImg1">
  <input type='file' class='uploader1' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text"></i>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container2">
  <img src="..." alt="Profile Image2" id='image2' class="profileImg2">
  <input type='file' class='uploader2' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. And telle us what you've try to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+upload+images+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Just added me code! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You changed both images every time

Instead delegate

Note I gave the ID of the image as a data attribute

I also suggest you use unique IDs instead of unique classnames

```js
const readURL = function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const preview = this.dataset.preview; 
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#'+preview)
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .width(300)
        .height();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}
$(function() {
  $("#main").on("change", "[type=file]", readURL)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="container1">
    <img src="..." alt="Profile Image1" id='image1' class="profileImg1">
    <input type="file" id="uploader1" data-preview="image1" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text"></i>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container2">
    <img src="..." alt="Profile Image2" id='image2' class="profileImg2">
    <input type="file" id="uploader2" data-preview="image2" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```